# Shopify variant link - show variant image of selection

Tags: javascript, ruby, shopify, liquid

On a store im working on, when you follow a link to a specific variant (/products/the-product?variant=12345678901) the image on the product page is the featured image of the product. It needs to be the variant image of the selected variant.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried editing product.liquid to:

`{% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image  %}`

`{% assign featured_image = variant.image %}`

but neither work.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to target this is the following.

```
{% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.image | img_url: 'master' %}
```

Refer to the Variant Object documentation: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/variant

Comment: This isn't working, I need to have it so when a variant link is followed it shows the selected variant image on the product page. Does that make sense?

Comment: And the provided code doesn't do that? I'm not sure if what you asking and what you are looking is the same thing.